# Cypher: how to update a property value in a node that exists in the Neo4j database?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Cypher question.
I have articles nodes with several properties. There is only one property value that I want to update in existing nodes.

For example I insert the node `(a:ARTICLE {id:1, title:'test', score=2}`.
The score value change during the day so I want to keep the node in the database but only update the score.

For example I would like to keep the node above in the DB with same id and title but only score value updated: `(a:ARTICLE {id:1, title:'test', score=3}`.
So I tried this:
To insert the articles in the database I do this:

```
"MERGE (a:ARTICLE {id:$id, title:$title}) SET a += {score:$score}"
```

But doesn't work the node is duplicated. How can I write well the request ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you must determine what set of properties make the `Article` nodes unique (side note: the PascalCase is more common for labels than UPPERCASE).

Let's assume `id` is unique per article.

In that case, you only need to merge on that:

```
MERGE (article:Article {id: $id})
// [...]
```

It's usually a good idea to create an index as well, so that the `MATCH`ing part of `MERGE` executes fast. In that case, you would create an index for `:Article(id)`.

Assuming the title never changes after the node creation:

```
MERGE (article:Article {id: $id})
ON CREATE SET article.title = $title
// [...]
```

Given the score **always** changes, you can then run a simple `SET` clause without any `ON CREATE` or `ON UPDATE` prefix:

```
MERGE (article:Article {id: $id})
ON CREATE SET article.title = $title
SET article.score = $score
```

Of course, I made a few assumptions about your domain. Feel free to comment if I got some of them wrong and I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the type of $id, maybe it's a string when you execute the update query. Tried with your example Neo4j doesn’t create a new node.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution:

`MATCH (a:ARTICLE {id:$id}) SET a.score = $score`